Build an Electron App (generate build & setup)
there,
I've been working for over 8 hours trying to generate setup and build my ElectronJS application (v18.0.0 mandatory).
Here is my package.json :
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "https://.../",
  "description": "(description)",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.my.app",
    "productName": "projectname",
    "copyright": "Copyright © 2024 Project Name",
    "directories": {
      "output": "dist"
    },
    "extraMetadata": {
      "version": "0.0.1 Beta",
      "description": "Test",
      "author": "OGHub.fr"
    },
    "protocols": {
      "name": "appname",
      "schemes": [
        "appname"
      ]
    },
    "files": [
      "main.js",
      "app/*",
      "scratch/*",
      "preload.js",
      "app/**/*"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "msi"
      ],
      "icon": "app/img/logo.ico",
      "publisherName": "Publisher Name"
    },
    "mac": {
      "target": [
        "dmg"
      ],
      "icon": "app/img/logo.ico"
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage",
        "deb",
        "rpm"
      ],
      "icon": "assets/icons/png"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "installerIcon": "app/img/logo.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "app/img/logo.ico",
      "installerHeader": "app/img/logo.ico",
      "include": "installer.nsh"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [
  ],
  "author": "Author name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "node-localstorage": "^3.0.5",
    "registry-js": "^1.16.0",
    "trucksim-telemetry": "^0.21.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^18.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^24.13.3"
  }
}

When I run npm run build, it generates these :
dist/
-> /win-unpacked
-> myapp.exe (good okay), BUT, i have in extrameta data “Github Inc”, “Version: v18.0.0” and “App Name: Electron”.
And, same, I don't know how to generate a “win-unpacked” setup anymore, the last time I had done something under electron was in 2018 with electron-wininstaller, but it doesn't work for me anymore.
Another thing, when I use electron build, I also have this information:
npm run build
Debugger attached.

> ogbridge@0.0.1 build
> electron-builder

Debugger attached.
  • electron-builder  version=24.13.3 os=10.0.22621
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=registry-js@1.16.0, trucksim-telemetry@0.21.0 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • install prebuilt binary  name=registry-js version=1.16.0 platform=win32 arch=x64 napi=
• packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=18.0.0 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  • downloading     url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z size=5.6 MB parts=1
  • downloaded      url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.6.0/winCodeSign-2.6.0.7z duration=1.191s
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 2
                    out=
    7-Zip (a) 21.07 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2021 Igor Pavlov : 2021-12-26

    Scanning the drive for archives:
    1 file, 5635384 bytes (5504 KiB)

    Extracting archive: AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\092952403.7z
    --
    Path = AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\092952403.7z
    Type = 7z
    Physical Size = 5635384
    Headers Size = 1492
    Method = LZMA2:24m LZMA:20 BCJ2
    Solid = +
    Blocks = 2


    Sub items Errors: 2

    Archives with Errors: 1

    Sub items Errors: 2

                    errorOut=ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : Le client ne dispose pas d'un privil�ge n�cessaire. : AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\098865179\darwin\10.12\lib\libcrypto.dylib
    ERROR: Cannot create symbolic link : Le client ne dispose pas d'un privil�ge n�cessaire. : AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\098865179\darwin\10.12\lib\libssl.dylib

                    command='Desktop\OGHub\OGBridge\electron13\node_modules\7zip-bin\win\x64\7za.exe' x -bd 'AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\098865179.7z' '-oAppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\098865179'
                    workingDir=AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign

Thank's !
electron-wininstaller ; electron forge ; electron-builder electron-packager.

This exact problem has also been exhibited in this question just now. Maybe you should file a bug report with the Electron Builder project?
